# How do you use two or more route.js files in Express Router in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

I am not running into any errors but I am wondering if this is the correct way to use two or more route.js files using `express.Router`. Am I using `module.exports = router` correctly as they are in two separate files, or is there a different way?

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");

const api = require("./routes/tracking.route");
const user = require("./routes/user.route");

const app = express();

app.use("/api", api);
app.use("/user", user);
```

**tracking.route.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const tracking_controller = require("../controllers/tracking.controller");

router.get("/list", tracking_controller.tracking_list);

module.exports = router;
```

**user.route.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const User = require("../models/user.model");

router.post("/signup", ...");

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: yes!!> no issue

Comment: @xdeepakv great, thank you!

Comment: This works fine.  The alternate syntax is the newer `import` and `export` syntax with the newer module format, but the concept is the same.  You export your router in the implementation file and then import it into your app.